# Cannot change CSS style with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm learning jQuery & JavaScript from scratch and cannot wrap my head around why css cannot be added with jQuery. Basically, I'm trying to see whether the the sentence bolds when the user clicks on the first sentence. I have been referencing w3school and external resources, but not sure why there is an error.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Question 3</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h3>Click on this heading to update below paragraph </h3>
    <p id="pText">this is a paragrah</p>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("h3").click(function() {
          $('pText').css("font-weight", "bold");
          document.getElementById('pText').innerHTML = "this is updated paragraph";
        });
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed to prefix the id symbol (`#`) in the selector:

```
$('#pText').css("font-weight", "bold");
```

I will also suggest you not mix up vanilla JS and jQuery unnecessarily.

You can replace

```
document.getElementById('pText').innerHTML = "this is updated paragraph";
```

with the following equivalent jQuery:

```
$('#pText').html("this is updated paragraph");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <h3>Click on this heading to update below paragraph </h3>
    <p id="pText">this is a paragrah</p>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("h3").click(function () {
                $('#pText').css("font-weight", "bold");
                $('#pText').html("this is updated paragraph"); // you can use jQuery here
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
```